# Filtering os.walk files on extension and size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small routine that reads the files in a directory and filters them by extension (.csv). I would also like to filter these files by file size.
For example files that are smaller than 100 bytes so that I only have files that have the extension (.csv) and are larger than 100 bytes.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CSVDIR):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file).replace('/', '/')
            filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]

            print (file)
```

Can i use?  `if os.stat().st_size >3`

Comment: please fix the indentation on the inner `for` loop

Comment: `.replace('/', '/')` <- What on earth?

Comment: *"Can i use `if os.stat().st_size >3`?"* Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: You clearly know how to get a file's size, so I'm really not sure what the question/problem here is...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.getsize` which I prefer. You also don't need to walk the tree looking for these files: you could just use glob with recursion:

```
import os
import glob
csvfiles = [file for file in glob.iglob('CSVDIR/**/*.csv',recursive=True) if os.path.getsize(file) > 100]
```

Anytime you're using recursion with glob.glob or glob.iglob you need to include the ** as I did in the file path search pattern. I used iglob here because I like how it returns an iterator, but you could use glob instead which returns a list - which you may want to do if you want to isolate the glob call from the list comprehension for inspection of its elements.

Answer (score 1):

@ Billiam Thank you answer also works but I have chosen a different solution for now.

@ Aran-Fey Why so aggressive.? I thought they also wanted to help starting programmers instead of giving agrasive comments.
Fortunately there are others who can understand a stupid question.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CSVDIR):
            for file in files:
                S = os.path.getsize((CSVDIR)+(file))
                if S > 3:
                    if file.endswith('.csv'):
                        print (file)
                        fullname = os.path.join(root, file).replace('/', '/')
                        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]

                        uri = 'file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&decimal=%s&useHeader=no&' % (fullname, 'EPSG:4326', ';', 'Field_8', 'Field_9', ',')
                        layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'my_layer', 'delimitedtext')
                        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, DESTDIR + '/' + filename + '.shp', 'CP1250', layer.crs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')
```